# Zoom an image when hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a website, so I have an image when I hover it I want it to zoom but the problem is the image zoom with a bad way it come out of a div how I can fix that?

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="" height="400" width="500"/>
</div>
```

My css style

```
.container{
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.container:hover img{
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cpsp4wdn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `overflow: hidden` to the div so the content will be clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible

```
.container{
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden
}
.container:hover img{
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ohv6y336/1/) ?

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden
}
.container img {        /* add this rule */
  width:100%;;
  height:100%;
  transition:all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.container:hover img {   /* change this rule */
  width:120%;
  height:120%;
  margin:-10% 0 0 -10%;
  transition:all 0.7s ease-in-out; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://motivationhacks.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/steve-jobs-black-white.jpg" alt="" height="400" width="500" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the most efficient method will be to use `scale` transition CSS property as follows,

```
.container{
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:hover img{
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

By using the scale property, the image would zoom smoothly on all devices including mobile devices. So you don't need to specify accurate height and width values for each and every device.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Much better than my "negative margin/fixed width" .. so I deleted mine and +1 for you.

Comment: @LGSon Ah, C'mon, why did you delete your answer in the first place? "negative margin/fixed width" too works and it's an answer right? :)

Comment: Yes it does work too, though as I found yours better/simpler/cleaner than any of the existing answer, I made the choice to up vote it and delete mine. Mine where also very close to the accepted one, and yet another almost the same as an existing, doesn't benefit future users.

Comment: I strongly disagree with you about deleting your answer. You upvoted mine, since it's "better/simpler/cleaner etc..", that's OK... But, you can't really decide whether your answer will benefit future users or not....